# Is there any way to "capture" the output of `g<`? (i.e. like how :redir works for other cmds)

Tags: command

I have some functions and mappings that echo paragraphs of summary output for me to "take a pulse" on some things I'm working on.

I know that if it disappears before I finish perusing, I can use `g<` to view it again.

Now...   I am hoping to capture that output.
I can edit my mappings to create splits instead of echoing -- but 99% of the time I prefer just echo and go away.

I also do not want to create duplicate mappings...  just more to remember.

Instead, for those very few times I want to capture that output so I can e-mail it, or compare it...    I am hoping to ***capture*** the output of `g<`.

I have tried the following.  Once this is figured out, the `LastOut` function could easily be edited to do something different (like create a split with the captured text):

```
function! LastOut() abort
    norm g<
endfunction
```

When I run this via a mapping:

```
map <expr> <leader>zz LastOut()
```

I get an error in the output:

```
Error detected while processing function LastOut:
line    1:
E523: Not allowed here
```

That error, `E523`, is about the `'secure'` option, so I am confused how it relates.

---

This works to simply re-display it:

```
map <expr> <leader>xx ':norm g<<cr>'
```

But this does NOT work to capture it:

```
map <expr> <leader>yy ':redir @"<cr>:norm g<<cr>:redir END<cr>'
```

The above mapping will re-display it each time it is invoked.

Also -- ***oddly*** - it will output more and more each time, appending a copy of the following 3 lines each time.

```
:redir @"
:norm g<
:redir END
```

_But_ -- the only thing going into `@"` each time is a `^J` character.

Any ideas?     Or does anybody know the bit in the docs that explicitly say this is not possible?

PS:    My vim version:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 9.0 (2022 Jun 28, compiled Jan 21 2023 23:28:50)
MS-Windows 64-bit GUI version with OLE support
Included patches: 1-1227
Compiled by appveyor@APPVYR-WIN
Huge version with GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
```

Comment: `:h g<` -- The "g<" output is not redirected.

Comment: would using `echom` be an option? Those are available in `:messages`

Comment: As Maxim said, it cannot currently be redirected: https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/79230f027a25ff12eb7c7b64e1c063297876aae2/src/testdir/test_normal.vim#L2862-L2870

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt -- that is a good link. Thank you. If you create an answer, I will mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the `g<` normal mode command cannot be redirected. We even have a [test case](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/79230f027a25ff12eb7c7b64e1c063297876aae2/src/testdir/test_normal.vim#L2862-L2870) in the Vim test-suite that is skipped, because it simply does not work.

This is also mentioned in the docummentation at [:h g<](https://vimhelp.org/message.txt.html#g%3C):

> The "g<" output is not redirected.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the test case.  The absolute ground truth on this :).